# finding $k$ and $y(t)$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I am looking for help with this homework problem I am really stuck on.

A function $y(t)$ is a solution of
$$y′+ky=0.$$
Suppose that $y(0)=100$ and $y(2)=4$.

Find $k$ and find $y(t)$.

I worked it to $y=e^{-c-kt}$ and plugged in $y(0)$ to get $y=100e^{-kt}$ and then found $k$ to be $\ln(5)$ but both were wrong. can anyone show me how they did it and what answer they found?

Comment: Your answers are correct. Perhaps you made a mistake in checking your answer?

Answer (score 1):

You are right.

$$y'+ky=0 \Leftrightarrow y(t)=y(0)e^{-kt} $$

so $y(0)=100$
and, $y(2)=4$, which leads to $100e^{-2k}=4\Leftrightarrow -2k = \ln(1/25)=-\ln(25)=-2\ln 5$

Answer (score 1):

You are right for the first part : $y=Ke^{-kt}, K \in \mathbb{R}$.

$y(0)=100 \Rightarrow 100=K \Rightarrow y=100e^{-kt}$
So you are still right.

$y(2)=4 \Rightarrow 100e^{-2k}=4 \Rightarrow e^{-2k}=\frac{1}{25} \Rightarrow-2k=-\ln25 \Rightarrow k=\frac{\ln25}{2}=\ln(5)  $

So you are right !

Answer (score 1):

The general solution to the ordinary differential equation

$$y′+ky=0$$

is

$$y=C e^{-kt}$$

and then applying $y(0)=100$ we can find that

$$y=100e^{-kt}$$

in the next step, consider $y(2)=4$ to get

$$4=100e^{-2k}$$

and then solve for $k$ to get

$$k=\ln{5}$$

and the final answer will be

$$\boxed{y=100 e^{-(\ln{5})t}}$$